# Call stack in the perf profiler

Tags: linux, profiling, perf

I'm running "perf" in the following way:

```
perf record -a --call-graph -p some_pid

perf report --call-graph --stdio
```

Then, I see this:

```
 1.60%     my_binary  my_binary                [.] my_func
           |
           --- my_func
              |          
              |--71.10%-- (nil)
              |          (nil)
              |          
               --28.90%-- 0x17f310000000a
```

I can't see which functions call my_func(). I see "nil" and "0x17f310000000a" instead. Am I doing something wrong? It is probably not a debug info problem because some symbols are shown while others are not shown.

More info:

- I'm runnning CentOS 6.2 (kernel 2.6.32-220.4.1).
- perf rpm - perf-2.6.32-279.5.2.el6.x86_64.

Comment: Related: [Weird Backtrace in Perf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60491534) - libraries often usually compiled normally, without `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`, so the `fp` method of backtracing won't work into / through their functions.  For libc6 specifically, [perf record with --call-stack fp fails to unwind main function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68081147) mentions some distros having a libc6-prof package with a version of it compiled with frame pointers, intended for use with profilers.

Answer (score 35):

Make sure you compiled the code with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` **gcc** option.

Comment: or try `perf record --call-graph dwarf` (which works without frame-pointer)

Comment: install debuginfo packages for the code you profile, most of the time you'll need glibc, ie debuginfo-install glibc

Comment: So, `perf record --call-graph dwarf` does NOT work (for me), and actively PREVENTS a callgraph from being recorded, even if one compiled with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` ... it took me many hours & hair-pulling before I realized that I MUST do `perf record --call-graph fp` to get a callgraph!

Comment: ```sudo perf record --call-graph lbr <program_name> ``` works for intel processors, no need to do a specific compilation of the program

Answer (score 18):

You're almost there, you're missing the `-G` option (you might need a more recent perf than the one installed on your system):

```
$ perf report --call-graph --stdio -G
```

From `perf help report`:

```
   -G, --inverted
       alias for inverted caller based call graph.
```

Comment: -G just changes order of call stack printing in `perf report`; if there is no full call stack recorded to `perf.data` at time of `perf record`, `-G` option will not help. Just need to enable frame pointers or dwarf (may be not ported to rh's 2.6.32) to decode frames at time of `record`: http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html#StackTraces "Omitting frame pointers is an evil compiler optimization that breaks debugger"

Comment: Note that `-G` on `perf record` (rather than `report`) selects by cgroup, in case anyone gets confusing errors about cgroups.