# Weird Backtrace in Perf

Tags: linux, trace, performancecounter, perf, call-graph

I used the following command to extract backtraces leading to user level `L3-misses` in a simple `evince` benchmark:

```
sudo perf record -d --call-graph dwarf -c 10000 -e mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss:uppp /opt/evince-3.28.4/bin/evince
```

As it is clear, the sampling period is quite large (10000 events between consecutive samples). For this experiment, the output of `perf script` had some samples similar to this one:

```
EvJobScheduler 27529 26441.375932:      10000 mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss:uppp:     7fffcd5d8ec0         5080022 N/A|SNP N/A|TLB N/A|LCK N/A
    7ffff17bec7f bits_image_fetch_separable_convolution_affine+0x2df (inlined)
    7ffff17bec7f bits_image_fetch_separable_convolution_affine_pad_x8r8g8b8+0x2df (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.34.0)
    7ffff17d1fd1 general_composite_rect+0x301 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.34.0)
  ffffffffffffffff [unknown] ([unknown])
```

At the bottom of the backtrace, there is a symbol called `[unknown]`, which seems OK. But then a line in `general_composite_rect()` is called. Is this backtrace OK?

AFAIK, the first caller in the backtrace should be something like `_start()` or `__GI___clone()`. But the backtrace is not in this form. What is wrong?

Is there any way to resolve the issue? Are the truncated (parts of) backtraces reliable?

Comment: Does `evince` do it's own user-space multitasking / context switching?  Or maybe something breaks stack backtracing.

Comment: `evince` uses  `__GI__clone()` for its threads and there are many backtraces containing this function.

Comment: To have full backtrace you should have evince and all libraries used by it to be compiled with correct dwarf debug info. Without debug info and when -fomit-frame-pointer is active (and it often is active by default) for any function in real backtrace, perf will break backtracing. What is reliable - Sample address (EIP) of the event itself (with LLC events only with PEBS ":ppp"). What is unreliable: sorting on self+children in `perf report -g` (use `perf report -g --no-children` to sort on self only). Also: do a several Ctrl-C when running `gdb /opt/evince-3.28.4/bin/evince` and do "backtrace".

Comment: Thanks. I use `perf script`. Is the upper part of truncated backtraces reliable in its output? Are you certain that the problem is with the debug info? I think that it can print raw addresses when debug info is not available, No? I have installed the debug info packages for all libraries except two or three of them, while about `20` percent of backtraces are truncated for sampling with `100` instructions between consecutive samples.

Comment: @TheAhmad, with x86_64 and -fomit-frame-pointer (often enabled) there is no default place in stack or in registers to do the unwinding/backtracing process. When counter overflows (every 10000 events), perf_events subsystem in kernel handles PMU interrupt and it tries to find frames of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack using the `-g method` (`--call-graph` option of record) of unwinding/backtracing. Without dwarf debuginfo perf interrupt handler can't restore some frame and backtracing process stops at some function without chance to reach main() or _start or  clone()/start_thread().

Comment: @osgx: In theory DWARF CFI unwind info isn't supposed to get stripped, and isn't considered debug info.  But in practice I think you can leave them out with `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables`.  I think normally `-fasynchronous-unwind-tables` is on by default, even for C, but build scripts might do something different.

Comment: So, if I add debug info for all packages, no backtrace will be truncated (even when `-fomit-frame-pointer` removes framepointers). Right?

Comment: @TheAhmad, You can: recompile every user library with -fno-omit-frame-pointer and use `--call-graph fp` with in-kernel stack backtracer; or use DWARF CFI and increased stack saved by kernel for user-space stack dump walker `--call-graph dwarf,81920`. DWARF CFI method will truncate too long backtraces.

Comment: Thanks. I should check with the size parameter. In the DWARF case, setting the size parameter to a sufficiently large value will resolve the truncation problem. Am I right?

Comment: @TheAhmad, larger size N for `--call-graph dwarf,N` may help (with larger parf.data files and more overhead; default N=8192). I don't know will it or not so I hope you will share your results (for example as additional answer to this question or to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277463)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR perf backtracing process may stop at some function if there is no frame pointer saved in the stack or no CFI tables for dwarf method. Recompile libraries with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` or with `-g` or get debuginfo. With release binaries and libs perf often will stop backtrace early without chance to reach `main()` or `_start` or `clone()/start_thread()` top functions.

`perf` profiling tool in Linux is statistical sampling profiler (without binary instrumentation): it programs software timer or event source or hardware performance monitoring unit (PMU) to generate periodic interrupt. In your example
`-c 10000 -e mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss:uppp` is used to select hardware PMU in x86_64 in some kind of PEBS mode (https://easyperf.net/blog/2018/06/08/Advanced-profiling-topics-PEBS-and-LBR) to generate interrupt after 10000 of mem_load_uops_retired (with l3_miss mask). Generated interrupt is handled by Linux Kernel ([perf_events subsystem](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.107/source/kernel/events), kernel/events and [arch/x86/events](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.107/source/arch/x86/events)). In this handler PMU is reset (reprogrammed) to generate next interrupt after 10000 more events and sample is generated. Sample data dump is saved into perf.data file by `perf report` command, but every wake of tool can save thousands of samples; samples can be read by `perf script` or `perf script -D`.

perf_events interrupt handler, something near [`__perf_event_overflow`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.107/source/kernel/events/core.c#L7837) of kernel/events/core.c, has full access to the registers of current function, and has some time to do additional data retrieval to record current time, pid, etc. Part of such process is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack data collection. But with x86_64 and -fomit-frame-pointer (often enabled for many system libraries of Debian/Ubuntu/others) there is no default place in registers or in function stack to store frame pointers:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fomit_002dframe_002dpointer-692

> `-fomit-frame-pointer`
>     Don't keep the frame pointer in a register for functions that don't need one. This avoids the instructions to save, set up and
>   restore frame pointers; it also makes an extra register available in
>   many functions. It also makes debugging impossible on some machines.
>
> Starting with GCC version 4.6, the default setting (when not optimizing for size) for 32-bit Linux x86 and 32-bit Darwin x86
>   targets has been changed to -fomit-frame-pointer. The default can be
>   reverted to -fno-omit-frame-pointer by configuring GCC with the
>   --enable-frame-pointer configure option.

With frame pointers saved in the function stack backtracing/unwinding is easy. But for some functions modern gcc (and other compilers) may  not generate frame pointer. So backtracing code like in perf_events handler either will stop backtrace at such function or needs another method of frame pointer recovery. Option `-g method` (`--call-graph`) of `perf record` selects the method to be used. It is documented in `man perf-record` http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-record.1.html:

> `--call-graph` Setup and enable call-graph (stack chain/backtrace) recording, implies -g. Default is "fp".
>
> Allows specifying "fp" (frame pointer) or "dwarf"    (DWARF's CFI -
>   Call Frame Information) or "lbr"    (Hardware Last Branch Record
>   facility) as the method to collect    the information used to show the
>   call graphs.
>
> In some systems, where binaries are build with gcc
>   --fomit-frame-pointer, using the "fp" method will produce bogus    call graphs, using "dwarf", if available (perf tools linked to    the
>   libunwind or libdw library) should be used instead.    Using the "lbr"
>   method doesn't require any compiler options. It    will produce call
>   graphs from the hardware LBR registers. The    main limitation is that
>   it is only available on new Intel    platforms, such as Haswell. It
>   can only get user call chain. It    doesn't work with branch stack
>   sampling at the same time.
>
> When "dwarf" recording is used, perf also records (user) stack dump
>   when sampled.  Default size of the stack dump is 8192 (bytes).    User
>   can change the size by passing the size after comma like
>   "--call-graph dwarf,4096".

So, dwarf method reuses CFI tables to find stack frame sizes and find caller's stack frame. I'm not sure are CFI tables stripped from release libraries by default or not; but debuginfo probably will have them. LBR will not help because it is rather short hardware buffer. Dwarf split processing (kernel handler saves part of stack and perf user-space tool will parse it with libdw+libunwind) may lose some parts of call stack, so try also to increase dwarf stack dumps by using `--call-graph dwarf,10240` or `--call-graph dwarf,81920` etc.

Backtracing is implemented in arch-dependent part of perf_events: [arch/x86/events/core.c:`perf_callchain_user()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.107/source/arch/x86/events/core.c#L2437); called from [kernel/events/callchain.c:`get_perf_callchain()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.107/source/kernel/events/callchain.c#L179) <- perf_callchain <-  [perf_prepare_sample](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.107/source/kernel/events/core.c#L6445) <- 
[__perf_event_output](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.107/source/kernel/events/core.c#L6569) <- [`*(event->overflow_handler)`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.107/source/kernel/events/core.c#L10111) <- `READ_ONCE(event->overflow_handler)(event, data, regs);` of [`__perf_event_overflow`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.107/source/kernel/events/core.c#L7837).

Gregg did warn about incomplete call stacks of perf: http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-06-22/perf-cpu-sample.html

> Incomplete stacks usually mean -fomit-frame-pointer was used – a compiler optimization that makes little positive difference in the real world, but breaks stack profilers. Always compile with -fno-omit-frame-pointer. More recent perf has a -g dwarf option, to use the alternate libunwind/dwarf method for retrieving stacks.

I also did write about backtraces in perf with some additional links: [How does linux's perf utility understand stack traces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277463)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was like this: when you are collecting traces with `--call-graph dwarf`, if the size of the stack is too big, you will get `unknown` in the stack backtrace.

The default maximum stack size is 8kB, but it can be increased like this, `--call-graph dwarf,16578`. Unfortunately, perf has some other problems when you increase the stack size. In my case, the solution was to get rid of a large stack-allocated array by allocating it on the heap.