# Why does gdb backtrace shows more detail that perf call stack?

Tags: c++, linux, libc, perf, backtrace

I've run some sample code through `perf`, and get the following top hotspot:

```
-   63.93%     0.10%  bonds    libc.so.6              [.] __GI___fstatat64                                                                                                                     
     63.82% __GI___fstatat64                                                                                                                                                                   
-   63.82%    63.82%  bonds    [unknown]              [k] 0xffffffffa90001a2                                                                                                                   
     __GI___fstatat64                                                                                                                                                                          
+    5.32%     0.00%  bonds    [unknown]              [.] 0000000000000000
```

From this, I can see that the majority of the time is spent in the `__GI___fstatat64` function inside glibc.  I'm now using `gdb` to debug this code to see what code paths lead to this area of the code.  As you can see, `perf` only shows me a very shallow call stack, i.e one function, where as gdb gives me the full backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI___fstatat64 (fd=fd@entry=-100, file=file@entry=0x7ffff59bb46b "/etc/localtime", buf=buf@entry=0x7fffffffd440, flag=flag@entry=0)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fstatat64.c:154
#1  0x00007ffff591d706 in __GI___stat64 (file=file@entry=0x7ffff59bb46b "/etc/localtime", buf=buf@entry=0x7fffffffd440)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/stat64.c:29
#2  0x00007ffff58eb174 in __tzfile_read (file=file@entry=0x7ffff59bb46b "/etc/localtime", extra=extra@entry=0, extrap=extrap@entry=0x0) at tzfile.c:159
#3  0x00007ffff58ead24 in tzset_internal (always=<optimized out>) at tzset.c:405
#4  0x00007ffff58eaf23 in __tz_convert (timer=1681057207, use_localtime=1, tp=0x7ffff59fd660 <_tmbuf>) at tzset.c:577
#5  0x00007ffff6da62ae in QuantLib::Date::todaysDate () at /mnt/hdd1/sandbox/temp/QuantLib/ql/time/date.cpp:770
#6  0x00007ffff67e4a35 in QuantLib::Settings::DateProxy::operator QuantLib::Date (
    this=0x7ffff7e238a0 <QuantLib::Singleton<QuantLib::Settings, std::integral_constant<bool, false> >::instance()::instance>)
    at /mnt/hdd1/sandbox/temp/QuantLib/ql/settings.hpp:136
#7  QuantLib::Bond::isExpired (this=0x7fffffffda00) at /mnt/hdd1/sandbox/temp/QuantLib/ql/instruments/bond.cpp:107
#8  0x000000000040eb9c in QuantLib::Instrument::calculate (this=0x7fffffffda00) at /usr/local/include/ql/instrument.hpp:148
#9  0x00000000004103fa in QuantLib::Instrument::NPV (this=this@entry=0x7fffffffda00) at /usr/local/include/ql/instrument.hpp:185
#10 0x000000000040e272 in go () at /mnt/hdd1/sandbox/work/cpp/quantlib/bonds.cpp:93
```

Show I not be able to see an equally rich call stack in `perf`?  I'm invoking `perf` like so with code compiled with `-Og -ggdb3`:

```
perf record -g ./bonds
perf report -g
```

Comment: According to the man page, `perf record --call-graph` defaults to `fp` (frame pointer) (not `dwarf` or `lbr`), but you maybe didn't compile with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`.  Unless `-Og` doesn't disable frame-pointers?  It's not clear from the man page what exactly `-g` does; `--call-graph` says it implies `-g` not that it's a synonym.

Comment: Relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60491534/weird-backtrace-in-perf

Answer (score 1):

Working through the provided comments to show how I arrived at a solution that gave me what I needed.

**Adding `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` compiler flag**

Now when I run `perf record` using the following command - `perf record -F 99 -g ./bonds` it certainly gives more detail, but still not really the full call stack I was looking for.

**Adding `--call-graph dwarf` to record stage**

This binary didn't have `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` flag set, but using the command - `perf record -F 99 --call-graph dwarf ./bonds` gives me pretty much exactly what I was looking for and very closely matches what I'm seeing in `gdb`

So in the context of my question, adding `--call-graph dwarf` to the record command appears to be the correct solution:

```
-   65.66%    65.66%  bonds    [unknown]              [k] 0xffffffffa90001a2                                                                                                                                                                                       ▒
     _start                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ◆
     __libc_start_main_alias_2 (inlined)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ▒
     __libc_start_call_main                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ▒
     main                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ▒
   - go                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ▒
      - 31.64% QuantLib::Bond::cleanPrice                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ▒
         - 16.64% QuantLib::Bond::settlementDate                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
              QuantLib::Settings::DateProxy::operator QuantLib::Date (inlined)                                                                                                                                                                                     ▒
              QuantLib::Date::todaysDate                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ▒
              __tz_convert                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ▒
              tzset_internal                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ▒
              __tzfile_read                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ▒
              __fstatat (inlined)
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot see a full call stack with `perf`, it just doesn't work in this way.
`perf` is a sampling profiler. Roughly speaking, it wakes up a number of times per second and records which function is being executed right now.
Basing on that, `perf report` shows you statistics.
Thus, functions that are called rarely (or executed too fast) just don't fall into it.